# Solving drush error

Tags: 7, drush

I am trying to use drush with an installation profile nodetream. But i get error like

```
Drush Error:


    C:\wamp\www\drupal9\profiles\nodestream>drush make --no-core --contrib-destinati
    on=. nodestream.make
    The drush command 'make nodestream.make' could not be found.             [error]

    Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.             [error]

    Hint: This error often occurs when Drush is trying to bootstrap a
    site that has not been installed or does not have a configured
    database.

    Drush was attempting to connect to :
      Drupal version    : 7.10
      Site URI          : http://default
      Default theme     : garland
      Administration theme: garland
      PHP configuration : C:\Program Files\Propeople\Drush\Php\php.ini
      Drush version     : 5.0-dev
      Drush configuration:
      Drush alias files :
      Drupal root       : C:/wamp/www/drupal9
      Site path         : sites/default
      Modules path      : sites/all/modules
      Themes path       : sites/all/themes
      File directory path: sites/default/files
      %paths            : Array

    You can select another site with a working database setup by
    specifying the URI to use with the --uri parameter on the command
    line or $options['uri'] in your drushrc.php file.


    C:\wamp\www\drupal9\profiles\nodestream>drush make --no-core --contrib-destinati
    on=. nodestream.make
    The drush command 'make nodestream.make' could not be found.             [error]

    Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.             [error]

    Hint: This error often occurs when Drush is trying to bootstrap a
    site that has not been installed or does not have a configured
    database.

    Drush was attempting to connect to :
      Drupal version    : 7.10
      Site URI          : http://default
      Default theme     : garland
      Administration theme: garland
      PHP configuration : C:\Program Files\Propeople\Drush\Php\php.ini
      Drush version     : 5.0-dev
      Drush configuration:
      Drush alias files :
      Drupal root       : C:/wamp/www/drupal9
      Site path         : sites/default
      Modules path      : sites/all/modules
      Themes path       : sites/all/themes
      File directory path: sites/default/files
      %paths            : Array

    You can select another site with a working database setup by
    specifying the URI to use with the --uri parameter on the command
    line or $options['uri'] in your drushrc.php file.
```

/** Update **/
I have put the drush_make folder under drush/commands folder also

Comment: What version of drush are you using? Can you double check you actually have drush make installed. I'm not sure where it should be installed on a windows box though.

Comment: @digital - I just installed drush 5.x and did not explicitly installed drush make. I am on a windows machine. How do i install drush make ?

Comment: Drush 5 should already have make included, your best bet would be to post in the drush issue queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Windows, presumably you are already using Drush-5; Drush-4 does not support Windows. Drush make is included in Drush-5, but unfortunately, Drush make is not supported on Windows either.

Try setting up [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), a free virtual machine solution, and install Drupal and Drush under ubuntu.

Comment: you mean to say drush will not work on windows ?

Comment: Sorry!  That was a typo!  I previously wrote "Drush-5 does not support Windows", but I -meant- to say "Drush-4 does not support Windows."  I have corrected the mistake above.  Drush-5 supports Windows, but not all functions work.  Notably, sql-sync and Drush make do not work yet.

Comment: so there is no way that drush make works on windows

Comment: A lot of work is being done on make in Drush core right now, and stuff that doesn't work on Windows is being fixed. What is really needed is someone to help fix problems in the issue queue.  Looking at your original problem again, though, it looks like perhaps make does not do what you think it does.  Make downloads the code you need for your site; you should *not* run it from within an existing site. It looks like you already have the code for your installation profile available. Maybe the Drush command you're looking for is site-install.

Comment: Its not an existing site. I just followed all the instructions given in the installation profile.

Comment: Try it again under Linux, then, perhaps via VirtualBox or VMWare, and see if you have better luck.

Answer (score 2):

Drush Make is now in Drush (see [issue](http://drupal.org/node/1310130)), so you shouldn't need to have `drush make` anywhere. Try running your command with the `--debug` flag and see what the output is?

Comment: I tried with out that also. Then also did not work.